# How increase the size of my plot when i am using control.bodeplot and see the lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use the control module of python for my transferfunctions. It works like a charm however i want to increase the size my bode plot that the module can produce. And see the log scale inside the plot.

This is the code i use in jupyter lab:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 14
import os
import control

f = np.logspace(0,6,1000)
f.min()
f.max()
len(f)
w = 2*np.pi*f
# s = 1.0j*w

s = control.TransferFunction.s

R1=31600
R2=5230
R3=4420
R4=5110

C1=10e-9
C2=1.8e-9
C3=150e-12

num = ((s*C2*(R1+R3)+1))*(s*C1*R2+1)
den = (s*R1*C1)*(s*C2*R3+1)*(s*R2*C3+1)

Hs = control.tf((num/den))
print(Hs)

plt.figure

out = control.bode_plot(Hs,w,dB=1,Hz=1,deg=1,plot=1,margins=1)
```

It shows the following:

[bodeplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvrff.png)

How can i have increase the size to make it better readable and how do i see de log lines????

Comment: edit: I found that plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 10.0,10.0 increases the image. But i still do not get the log lines back

Comment: What do you mean by log lines? Grid lines?

Comment: I found what i wanted. Used the margin option in the control.bode. This eliminates the grid lines. With that option disabled i got a good bodeplot with the grid lines.